# Url routing not working in my node.js application with iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis, express, url-rewriting, iisnode

I am working in a project "Integration of node.js with asp.net mvc application". So i use IISNode concept for this which i referred from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode). This works fine. But when i add routing concepts using express , the routing doestn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the URL Rewrite module installed on IIS.
Take a look here at the Prerequisites:
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode